# Find if there is a route between 2 nodes Depth first search

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I am using Depth first search and graphs to find if there is a route between 2 nodes or not.
But For some reason my method always results false even if there is a path.

**Here is my search code:**

```
static boolean search(Graph g, Node start, Node end)
{

if(start == null || end == null) return false;

start.state = State.Visited;

for(Node u: start.getChildNodes())
{
    if(u.state != State.Visited)
    {
        if(u.equals(end))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            u.state = State.Visited;
            search(g,u,end);
        }
    }
}

return false;
```

}

**I am calling the method like this:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Graph gDfs = createNewGraph();

        System.out.println("path between A & B");
        System.out.println(search(gDfs,gDfs.getNode()[0],gDfs.getNode()[1]));
    }
```

**createNewGraph()**

```
public static Graph createNewGraph()
{

Graph g = new Graph();        
Node[] temp = new Node[8];

temp[0] = new Node("A", 3);
temp[1] = new Node("B", 3);
temp[2] = new Node("C", 1);
temp[3] = new Node("D", 1);
temp[4] = new Node("E", 1);
temp[5] = new Node("F", 1);

temp[0].addChildNode(temp[1]);
temp[0].addChildNode(temp[2]);
temp[0].addChildNode(temp[3]);

temp[1].addChildNode(temp[0]);
temp[1].addChildNode(temp[4]);
temp[1].addChildNode(temp[5]);

temp[2].addChildNode(temp[0]);
temp[3].addChildNode(temp[0]);
temp[4].addChildNode(temp[1]);
temp[5].addChildNode(temp[1]);

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
{
    g.addNode(temp[i]);
}
return g;
```

}

*@amit => is this your suggestion?*

```
for(Node u: start.getChildNodes())
        {
            if(u.state != State.Visited)
            {
                if (search(g,u,end)) return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: See Amit's answer. In addition, make sure Node.equals() is implemented properly, otherwise you may also get false when the route exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always better to work just with current state, not next or prevous (no matter, dfs, or bfs).

```
boolean search(Graph g, Node current, Node target)
{

    if (current == null || target == null) return false;

    current.state = State.Visited;

    if (current == target) return true;

    for(Node u: current.getChildNodes())
    {
        if(u.state != State.Visited && search(g,u,target))
        {                
            return true;
        }
    }    
    return false;    
}
```

And "state" of some vertex may be not marked as "State.Visited" even if it's achievable from "A". It may cause some errors, or wrong complexity estimation. I suggest to check worst case with

```
void search(Graph g, Node v)
{
    v.state = State.Visited;     

    for(Node u: v.getChildNodes())
    {
        if(u.state != State.Visited)
        {                
            search(g,u);
        }
    }        
}
```

and check whether "B.state" is "State.Visited"

Comment: I tried the first implementation and it still returns false

Comment: @fscore try the second then. If if will return false too - path doesn't exist. It's a definition-like implementation.

Comment: I am trying paths between A & B as per my example and since A and B are root and child.. there is a route for sure..

Comment: How can I test 2nd one as there is nothing to indicate if there is path or not?

Comment: @fscore B.state == State.visited mean that dfs found a way from A to B somehow.

Comment: right. but in 2nd code whr r we marking nodes to be visited?

Comment: @fscore start.state = State.Visited;

Comment: right.. but thats a start node that we are marking as visited but we are not marking other nodes as visited

Comment: @fscore we're calling search(g,u,end), that mean now "u" will be "start". And will be marked as visited as expected

Comment: got it thanks a lot. But do you know why first code is not working. When I add a if clause of end.state = state.visited in first code then it works but that means there is no need to check if(u.state != State.Visited && search(g,u,end))

Comment: @fscore I've changed variable names. In this new terms there is no need to check whether target is visited. Now we're in "current", it will become visited. And if current == target, that mean path is found.

Comment: But do u know why first implementation doesnt work? it returns false in first one.. would like to understand

Comment: @fscore the best thing I can suggest is to send current, target names to output and look what it is between recurscive calls. I think there can be some errors in equalto() or smth else. But I'm pretty sure that given code is right. I wrote dfs algorithm for ~90-100 times, and it looks as it was before.

Comment: well its not entering in the condition of "u.state != State.Visited" I tried printing values

Comment: @fscore try to run my C++ code on ideone.com http://ideone.com/cuc0PU with testing data, look how it works and debug your version

Answer (score 3):

Your recursive call should end in yielding true if it also yielded true:

```
if (search(g,u,end)) return true;
```

Otherwise, you don't do anything with the value returned from it, and will just get to the end of the `for` loop and ultimately yield `false`.

As a side note, a better practice for checking if current node is the target node is NOT in the `for` loop, but as a new stop clause before it. Note that your method will fail for `search(G,start,start)`, though there is a path (of length 0) between every node and itself.

Comment: Missed the "else don't do anything" part. Sorry :)

Comment: @amit which line should I make the change as in the else part, I replaced search with the line u mentioned

Comment: I am not following the question, the `if` in the line I proposed should not have a following `else`, if the condition is not true, you just need to go on to the next iteration.

Comment: @amit I understood what you mean but still no result. you mean '''for(Node u: start.getChildNodes())
  {
   if(u.state != State.Visited)
   {
    if (search(g,u,end)) return true;
   }
  } '''

Comment: @fscore And where did you put your stop clause? (if the current node is he target node)

Comment: @amit check my edit.. can u please copy my search method in your comment and show me the exact change.